# JSON-like data format

Tags: json

I have this strange data format which I need to parse. It looks quite similar to JSON, but it's not - and JSON parsers crash when trying to parse it. I was wondering if anyone knows what this data format is. It looks like this:

```
{key1, [{1, 'some_value'}]}.
{'key2',
    [{key3, "value"},
     {key4, [{key5, "some_value"}, {key6, 24}, {key7, "some_value"}, {key8, "some_value"}]}
]
}.
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide some context on this ? What generated the data, for example?